# Replace all instances in string with unique replacement

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm attempting to replace all instances of a particular String with a unique replacement.

**What I would like:**

If I have this String:

```
String testScript = "while(true) { } while   (10 < 7) { } while((10 < 7)) { }";
```

I would like this output:

```
while(arg0 < 5000 && true) { } while(arg1 < 5000 && 10 < 7) { } while(arg2 < 5000 && (10 < 7)) { }
```

**What I have:**

However, the string passed in to `replaceAll` doesn't get queried again (obvious now I think about it).

```
while(arg0 < 5000 && true) { } while(arg0 < 5000 && 10 < 7) { } while(arg0 < 5000 && (10 < 7)){ }
```

Any answers or comments, as always, are greatly appreciated.

**SSCCE:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int counter = 0;
     String testScript = "while(true) { } while   (10 < 7) { } while((10 < 7)) { }";
     String out = testScript.replaceAll("while\\s*\\(", "while(arg" + (counter++) + " < 5000 && ");
     System.out.println(out);
}
```

Comment: Well, 10 is never less then 7. So why not use `false`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex replace with the count of the match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892276/regex-replace-with-the-count-of-the-match)

Comment: @ElliotFrisch which raises the question, why have the while block at all? :)

Comment: Arbitrary string for testing purposes. Thanks for the helpful comments, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` methods from `Matcher` class.

Both these methods require temporary buffer in which new (replaced) version of string will be placed. In this case `StringBuffer` is used.

Their purpose is to add to buffer chunks of modified text

- `appendReplacement(StringBuffer sb, String replacement)` when match will be found text from last match (or in case of first match from start of the string) till start of current match + replacement
- `appendTail(StringBuffer sb)` when there is no match left, but we also need to add text after last match (or if there was no match entire original string).

In other words if you have text `xxxxfooxxxxxfooxxxx` and you want to replace `foo` to `bar` matcher will need to invoke

```
                       xxxxfooxxxxxfooxxxx
1. appendReplacement   ^^^^^^^              will add to buffer xxxxbar
1. appendReplacement          ^^^^^^^^      will add to buffer xxxxxbar
3. appendTail                         ^^^^  will add to buffer xxxx
```

so after this buffer will contain `xxxxbarxxxxxbarxxxx`.

Demo

```
String testScript = "while(true) { } while   (10 < 7) { } while((10 < 7)) { }";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("while\\s*\\(");
Matcher m = p.matcher(testScript);

int counter = 0;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while(m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "while(arg"+ (counter++) + " < 5000 && ");
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
while(arg0 < 5000 && true) { } while(arg1 < 5000 && 10 < 7) { } while(arg2 < 5000 && (10 < 7)) { }
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much. (Will accept when I can)