# find consequent row of numbers (separated by non alphabetic characters) and count them

Tags: java, regex

I wanted to know how to achieve the following scenarios with java regex:

- find all consequent numbers in a string which are not separated by alphabetic characters, count them, and if the number of digits is between 4 and 5(5 included), then replace them with `"*"`

Examples:

- `"0000"`  will become `"****"`
- `"any text 000 00 more texts"` will become `"any text ***** more texts"`..notice that the space is removed
- `"any text 000 00 more texts 00"` will become `"any text ***** more texts 00"`
- `"any text 000 00 more texts 00 00"` will become `"any text ***** more texts ****"`
- `"any text 00-00 more texts 00_00"` will become `"any text **** more texts ****"`

To find the numbers I have tried:

- `(\d*)(?=[^a-bA-Z]*)` and
- `(\d*)([^a-bA-Z])(\d*)`
- `(\d*)([^a-bA-Z])(\d*)`

But even matching the cases does not work.

I need more understanding of how to do regex operations.

Comment: What if we have `foo 123 56 78 bar`? Should it not be replaced with `*` or maybe we should expect something like `foo ***** 78 bar`?

Comment: It should not be replaced with '*'

Comment: @Pshemo you have 7 consequent numbers not separated by alphabetic characters, so the condition should not match I guess

Comment: This is the [working demo](https://ideone.com/EN927z). And a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qS3jQ6/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Would you please suggest me some regex related tutorials or books you followed? or which one be the best way to learn regex?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure my suggestion should be posted. Please test and if it works OK, does not freeze anything and no stack overflow errors appear, I will post.

Comment: And I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are great. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew From what I see it doesn't handle correctly example from my comment: https://ideone.com/IJcUix (unless I misunderstood OP response).

Comment: @pshemo That is another reason why I do not post it - the lookahead boundaries should be adjusted.

Comment: My approach won't work well in Java (yes, we can use a constrained width lookbehind, but it is rather clumsy), good there are lots of answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern
        .compile( "(?<!\\d[^a-z\\d]{0,10000})"
                + "\\d([^a-z\\d]*\\d){3}([^a-z\\d]*\\d)?"
                + "(?![^a-z\\d]*\\d)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

public static String replaceSpecial(String text) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(2) == null ? "****" : "*****");
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Usage demo:

```
System.out.println(replaceSpecial("foo 123 56 78 bar 12 32 abc 000_00"));
System.out.println(replaceSpecial("0000"));
System.out.println(replaceSpecial("any text 00 00 more texts"));
System.out.println(replaceSpecial("any text 000 00 more texts 00"));
System.out.println(replaceSpecial("any text 000 00 more texts 00 00"));
System.out.println(replaceSpecial("any text 00-00 more texts 00_00"));
```

Result:

```
foo 123 56 78 bar **** abc *****
****
any text **** more texts
any text ***** more texts 00
any text ***** more texts ****
any text **** more texts ****
```

Idea/explanation:

We want to find series of digits which have between *zero or more* non-digit but also non-alphabetic characters (we can represent them via `[^\\da-z]` but IMO `[^a-z\\d]` looks better so I will use this form). Length of this series is 4 or 5 which we can write as

```
digit([validSeparator]*digit){3,4} //1 digit + (3 OR 4 digits) => 4 OR 5 digits
```

but we need to have some way to recognize if we matched 4 or 5 digits because we need to have some way to decide if we want to replace this match with 4 or 5 asterisks.
For this purpose I will try to put 5th digit in separate group and will test if that group is empty. So I will try to create something like `dddd(d)?`.

And that how I came up with

```
  "\\d([^a-z\\d]*\\d){3}([^a-z\\d]*\\d)?"
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ possible 5th digit
```

Now to need to make sure that our regex will match only `dddd(d)` which are not surrounded by any digit from left or right because we don't want to match any of cases like

```
d ddddd
 dddddd
 ddddd d
```

So we need to add tests which will check if before (or after) our match there will be no digit (and valid separator). We can use here negative-look-around mechanisms like

- `"(?<!\\d[^a-z\\d]{0,10000})"` - I used `{0,10000}` instead of `*` because look-behind needs to have some maximal length which prevents us from `*`.
- `"(?![^a-z\\d]*\\d)"`

So now all we needed to do is combine these regexes (and make it case insensitive or instead of `a-z` use `a-zA-Z`)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?<!\\d[^a-z\\d]{0,10000})"
                           + "\\d([^a-z\\d]*\\d){3}([^a-z\\d]*\\d)?"
                           + "(?![^a-z\\d]*\\d)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Rest is simple usage of `appendTail` and `appendReplacement` methods from Matcher class which will let us decide dynamically what to use as replacement of founded match (I tried to explain it better here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25081783/1393766)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method you can try:

```java
s = s.replaceAll ("\\d{5}", "*****").replaceAll("\\d{4}", "****")
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    s = s.replaceAll("(\\d{" + i + "})([^A-Za-z]*)(\\d{" + (5 - i) + "})", "*****");
}
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    s = s.replaceAll("(\\d{" + i + "})([^A-Za-z]*)(\\d{" + (4 - i) + "})", "****");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
(?<!\d|\d[_\W])(?=(\d|(?<=\d)[_\W]\d){4,5}(?!\d|[_\W]\d))\d|(?<=(?!^)\G)[_\W]?\d
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oU4hN4/3)

The `(?<!\d|\d[_\W])(?=(\d|(?<=\d)[_\W]\d){4,5}(?!\d|[_\W]\d))\d` part match for a digit, if:

- is not preceded by digit or digit followed by alphabetical char,
- is followed by 4-5 digits or combinations of digit and non
  alphabetical char
- after 4-5 digits/combination doeasn't occur another digit or
  combination,

The `(?<=(?!^)\G)[_\W]?\d` part match if:

- it follows another match, but not the beginning of line,
- is a digit, or combination of digit and non alphabetical char,

Example in Java:

```
public class RegexExample {
    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        String[] examples = {"0000","any text 000 00 more texts","any text 000 00 more texts 00",
                "any text 000 00 more texts 00 00","any text 00-00 more texts 00_00","test 00 00 00 00 00 test"};

        for(String example : examples) {
            System.out.println(example.replaceAll("(?<!\\d|\\d[_\\W])(?=(\\d|(?<=\\d)[_\\W]\\d){4,5}(?!\\d|[_\\W]\\d))\\d|(?<=(?!^)\\G)[_\\W]?\\d","*"));
        }
    }
}
```

with output:

```
****
any text ***** more texts
any text ***** more texts 00
any text ***** more texts ****
any text **** more texts ****
test 00 00 00 00 00 test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?:(?:\d[- _]*){6,})|(?<num_1>\d[- _]*)(?<num_2>\d[- _]*)(?<num_3>\d[- _]*)(?<num_4>\d)(?<num_5>[- _]*\d)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rA3vP7/1)

Explanation:
`(?:(?:\d[- _]*){6,})`: no capture matches row of 6+ numbers
`(?<num1>\d[- _]?)(?<num2>\d[- _]?)(?<num3>\d[- _]?)(?<num4>\d)(?<num5>[- _]?\d)?`: captures row of 4-5 numbers.

Input

```
"1-2-3-4-5-6" => no
"1-2-3-4-5"   => yes match 1
"1-2-3-4"     => yes match 2
"1-2-3"       => no
"123456"      => no
"12345"       => yes match 3
"1234"        => yes match 4
"123"         => no
foo 123 56 78 bar
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
num_1   [21-23] `1-`
num_2   [23-25] `2-`
num_3   [25-27] `3-`
num_4   [27-28] `4`
num_5   [28-30] `-5`
MATCH 2
num_1   [50-52] `1-`
num_2   [52-54] `2-`
num_3   [54-56] `3-`
num_4   [56-57] `4`
MATCH 3
num_1   [119-120]   `1`
num_2   [120-121]   `2`
num_3   [121-122]   `3`
num_4   [122-123]   `4`
num_5   [123-124]   `5`
MATCH 4
num_1   [148-149]   `1`
num_2   [149-150]   `2`
num_3   [150-151]   `3`
num_4   [151-152]   `4`
```

Then replace them with `*` : )