# Replacing String Space With Increasing numbers

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace a `String` space with  an increment `integer` the String looks like this (for example):

```
String str = "Im beginner Java Developer "
```

how can I solve it to be

```
im1beginner2Java3Developer4
```

I try `str.replace`
but the problem how I can put it in the `String` parameter function (replace)

Comment: A `for-loop` and `StringBuffer` come to find

Comment: You won't be able to do this with regex [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10892276/1743880). A simple way is a loop with a `StringBuilder`. Could you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient solution, but possibly the clearest:

```
String str = "Im beginner Java Developer ";
int count = 0;
while (str.contains(" "))
    str = str.replaceFirst(" ", String.valueOf(++count));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

```
    String str = "Im beginner Java Developer ";

    int index = str.indexOf(" ", 0);
    int count = 1;
    StringBuilder strbild = new StringBuilder(str);
    while (index != -1) {

        strbild.replace(index, index + 1, String.valueOf(count));
        index = str.indexOf(" ", index + 1);
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println(strbild);
```

Use StringBulider to replace the the elements of the String.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java 8

```
    String str = "Im beginner Java Developer ";
    String[] splitted = str.split("\\s+", -1);
    String result = IntStream.range(0, splitted.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> i + splitted[i])
        .collect(Collectors.joining()).substring(1);
    System.out.println(result);
```