# Is it possible to switch between + and - using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, replace

```
6*x + 7 = 7*x + 2 - 3*x
```

When we move the right hand side to the left of the equation, we need to flip the operator sign from + to - and vice versa.

Using java regex `replaceAll`, we're able to replace all +'s with -'s. As a result, all the operator signs become -'s, making it impossible for us to recover all the +'s.

As a workaround, I'm iterating through the string and changing + to - when encountering one and vice versa. But I still wonder if there's a way to flip between boolean value pairs using regex in Java?

Comment: You really shouldn't work on mathematical formulas with regex. Use a tokenizer and work with the tokens.

Comment: Generate a syntax tree from the string, operate on the tree, then render back to string. Much less hassle and far less error prone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this trick :

```
String equation = "<Your equation>"
equation = equation.replaceAll("+","$$$");
equation = equation.replaceAll("-","+");
equation = equation.replaceAll("$$$","-");
```

Assuming $$$ is not in your equation.

Comment: Not very efficient using 3 replaceAll. Besides, you forgot to assign the result of replaceAll to `equation`.

Comment: Hey I showed him a trick. I did not say it was efficient, It is just more elegant than iterating

Comment: And besides If his equations are not super large this solution will work fast enough to consider trading it off with some more fast but complicated algorithm

Comment: I did consider the idea of using temporary variable. You may be aware temporary variable is not necessary when doing value swapping in languages like Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP one can do following:

```
function swap($m) {
    return ($m[0]=='-')?'+':'-';
}
echo preg_replace_callback( '(\+|\-)', 'swap', '1 + 2 - 3 + 4 - 5');
```

Comment: For JAVA:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375420/java-equivalent-to-phps-preg-replace-callback