# Java RegEx: Replace all xml characters with their entity number

Tags: java, regex, actionscript-3, replace, xml-entities

I am trying to port a function I wrote in ActionScript to Java and I am having a bit of trouble. I have included the function below. I found [this response to question #375420](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563382/1762224), but do I really need to write a separate class? Thanks.

```javascript
public static function replaceXML(str:String):String {
  return str.replace(/[\"'&<>]/g, function($0:String):String {
    return StringUtil.substitute('&#{0};', $0.charCodeAt(0));
  });
}
```

**Input**

```
<root><child id="foo">Bar</child></root>
```

**Output**

```
&#60;root&#62;&#60;child id=&#34;foo&#34;&#62;Bar&#60;/child&#62;&#60;/root&#62;
```

---

***UPDATE***

Here is my solution if anyone is wondering. Thanks [Sri Harsha Chilakapati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026805).

```java
public static String replaceXML(final String inputStr) {
  String outputStr = inputStr;
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[&<>'\"]").matcher(outputStr);
  String found = "";
  while (m.find()) {
    found = m.group();
    outputStr = outputStr.replaceAll(found,
      String.format("&#%d;", (int)found.charAt(0)));
  }
  return outputStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for that.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String myString = "<root><child id=\"foo\">Bar</child></root>";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}\\p{N};\"+*/-]").matcher(myString);

while (m.find()) {
    String found = m.group();
    myString = myString.replaceAll(found, "&#" + (int)found.charAt(0) + ";");
}

System.out.println(myString);
```

It's working.

Output is

```
&#60;root&#62;&#60;child&#32;id&#61;"foo"&#62;Bar&#60;/child&#62;&60;/root&#62;
```

Comment: I tried grouping before with no luck, although my regex was not as intricate as yours. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: So, you are matching everything except: letters, numbers, semi-colon, double-quotes, plus, asterisk, forward-slash, & dash. Am I correct? Anyways, I will update my question with the solution I came up with if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

Well Java is an object oriented language, and therefore working with objects. Usually you can create a Util class, e.g. `RegExUtil` and provide a static method to invoke the method from any other class. The util class itself, shouldn't be instantiated. You can achieve that with a private Constructor.

```
public class RegExUtil {

  private RegExUtil(){
    //do nth.
  }

  public static String replaceXML(String input){
    //do sth.
  }
}
```

You should lookup Apache Commons first, because they may already provide a solution for your objective or at least you see how Util classes are made up.

Comment: I understand that Apache offers a JAR that is capable of achieving what I have asked for in my question, but I really wanted to see if there was a way to port the ActionScript code I had written in a similar fashion. Thanks.