# Use the backreference in a regex to replace a text dynamically

Tags: java, regex, backreference, replaceall

I want to use the $1 value like an integer.
The idea is to replace all numbers from originaltext with the equivalent array values and create a new text.
The below desired outcome should be "This is DBValue4, This is DBValue2, This is DBValue7"
Also, is there a way to save these backreferences for further use?

```
String[] values = {"DBValue0","DBValue1","DBValue2","DBValue3","DBValue4","DBValue5","DBValue6","DBValue7","DBValue8","DBValue9","DBValue10"};
String originaltext = "This is 4, This is 2, This is 7";
text = originaltext.replaceAll("(\\d)","$1");
// want something like
text = originaltext.replaceAll("(\\d)",values[$1]);
//or
text = originaltext.replaceAll("(\\d)",values[Integer.parseInt("$1")]);
```

Comment: Use a `Pattern` and `Matcher`

Comment: You can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375420/java-equivalent-to-phps-preg-replace-callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String[] values = {"DBValue0", "DBValue1", "DBValue2", "DBValue3", "DBValue4", "DBValue5", "DBValue6", "DBValue7", "DBValue8", "DBValue9", "DBValue10"};
    final String originaltext = "This is 4, This is 2, This is 7";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=This is )\\d++");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(originaltext);
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
        final int index = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, values[index]);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Output:

```
4
2
7
This is DBValue4, This is DBValue2, This is DBValue7
```

**EDIT**

Further to the OP's comment is seems that the OP needs to replace `String`s of the form `{name, index}` where "name" is the name of an array and "index" is the index of an element in that array.

This is easily achieved by `Map`ping the arrays to their names using a `Map<String, String[]>` and then using a `Pattern` that captures first the `name` then the `index`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String[] companies = {"Company1", "Company2", "Company3"};
    final String[] names = {"Alice", "Bob", "Eve"};
    final String originaltext = "This is {company, 0}, This is {name, 1}, This is {name, 2}";
    final Map<String, String[]> values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put("company", companies);
    values.put("name", names);
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{([^,]++),\\s*+(\\d++)}");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(originaltext);
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        final int index = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, values.get(matcher.group(1))[index]);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Output:

```
company
0
name
1
name
2
This is Company1, This is Bob, This is Eve
```

Comment: I'm sorry but for reasons of simplicity, the example is not so good. What you have done, works but I want to use something more complicated like " String originaltext = "{company,3} sents this message for {name,2} owner of the number {number,10} from {new,11}"; " and " text = originaltext.replaceAll("\\{.+?,(\\d\\d?)\\}",values[Integer.parseInt("$1")]); ". Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand - so you have several arrays and you want to select between them on a `String`?

Comment: No, I just want to replace {something,an_int} in any text with the values[an_int] array property.

Comment: My edit should do that for you if you make a couple of changes.