# Java: replace a set of characters with other different characters

Tags: java, regex, char

I am supposed to make a custom decorator so I can replace both in an input from console and from a file:

1. A set of chars with a specific character (e.g. `char[] x = {'a', 'b'}` with `char y = '*'`, so both `a` and `b` become `*`
2. A set of chars with another set of paired chars (e.g. `char[] x = {'a', 'b'}` with `char[] y = {'c', 'd'}`, so `a` becomes `c` and `b` becomes `d`

What would be the best approach for it? I made the first one with a regular expression ( `String replaceAll = s.replaceAll("(a|b)", String.valueOf(replacement));` ), but this wouldn't work for the second case. Is there a way to make the second case in one regex? Should I do a HashMap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to first create some kind of mapping between replaced character and its replacement. I mean something like

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "c");
map.put("b", "d");
```

then you can use `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` from Matcher class to replace matched character. Deciding on how to get replaced character can be done like `map.get(matchedCharacter)`.

### Simple Demo

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "c");
map.put("b", "d");

String demo = "abcdef";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[ab]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(demo);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb, map.get(m.group()));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String replaced = sb.toString();

System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output: `cdcdef`

---

### UPDATE for Java 9 and above

In below template we usually change only one thing, decision about what to use as replacement of founded match.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb, /* decision about replacement*/ );
    //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String replaced = sb.toString();
```

So since rest of that logic is repeated, this template was wrapped as [`String replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) which require from us to provide logic of obtaining replacement for founded match. So above code can be reduced to:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "c");
map.put("b", "d");

String demo = "abcdef";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[ab]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(demo);

String replaced = m.replaceAll(match -> map.get(match.group()));
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Answer (score 1):

DjMike,

For the second one, what would be helpful during the replacement is to call a method that you infuse with the logic to replace different characters with different strings.

PHP has a great facility that does just this called preg_replace_callback(). The linked answer is to a question about the [Java equivalent of preg_replace_callback()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375420/java-equivalent-to-phps-preg-replace-callback)

Comment: I was looking for the same preg_replace_callback() style implementation, since I know PHP very well, but this seems way too complicated at this time and I also implemented the solution I marked as an answer. Thank you for your effort anyway. I would have preffered the regex style, but it is what it is for now. Good to know for the future.

Comment: Ha, we were on the same track. Glad you found a solution DJ, wishing you a fun weekend. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have, this work 100% right for any example ....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "My name is Baba";

        Character[] x = { 'a', 'b' };

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("(");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (i == (x.length - 1)) {
                sb.append(x[i] + ")");
            } else {
                sb.append(x[i] + "|");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        Character y = 'c';
        Character[] y1 = { 'd', 'e' };

        if (y.getClass().isArray()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < y1.length; i++) {
                test = test.replaceAll(x[i].toString(), y1[i].toString());
            }
        } else {
            test = test.replaceAll(sb.toString(), String.valueOf(y.toString()));
        }

        System.out.println(test);
    }
```

Comment: Seems pretty good and simple solution. Although I have already chose the @Pashemo's answer and also implemented it, I will give you a plus for your effort. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a more faster way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String target      = "ab";
    String replacement = "**";

    char[] array = "abcde".toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int index = target.indexOf(array[i]);
        if (index != -1) {
            array[i] = replacement.charAt(index);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(array);
}
```