# Get what was removed by String.replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

So, let's say I got my regular expression

```
String regex = "\d*";
```

for finding any digits.

Now I also got a inputted string, for example

```
String input = "We got 34 apples and too much to do";
```

Now I want to replace all digits with "", doing it like that:

```
input = input.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

When now printing input I got "We got  apples and too much to do". It works, it replaced the 3 and the 4 with "".

Now my question: Is there any way - maybe an existing lib? - to get what actually was replaced?

The example here is very simple, just to understand how it works. Want to use it for complexer inputs and regex.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375420/java-equivalent-to-phps-preg-replace-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Matcher` with the append-and-replace procedure:

```
String regex = "\\d*";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer replaced = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()) {
    replaced.append(matcher.group());
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "");
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);

System.out.println(sb.toString());  // prints the replacement result
System.out.println(replaced.toString()); // prints what was replaced
```

Comment: Shorter than what @Enissay said and works! Thanks alot!