# Regular expression to remove -

Tags: regex

Hi im new to regular expression. Just want to know how to remove '-' in specific tag in document. I only want to remove the '-' in `<TN>` tag. Thanks!

```
<BusinessLine> <TN>905-694-9734</TN> <Type>buslinetype-HG</Type> <Status>InService</Status> </BusinessLine>
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, an HTML parser would probably be a better bet for this.

Comment: which language? please try my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=<TN>.*?)\-(?=.*?</TN>)
```

**For Java:**

```
your_string= your_string.replaceAll("(?sim)(?<=<TN>.*?)\\-(?=.*?</TN>)", "");
```

Comment: i need it in java pattern coz it is in .net pattern . can you convert it? thanks in advance

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Please check i have updated the answer.

Comment: i usually use the regex for nifi. not in scripting

Comment: if using php I would use the preg_replace_callback function for JAVA I use a class found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375420/java-equivalent-to-phps-preg-replace-callback/375479?noredirect=1#comment2566951_375479

Comment: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 10

when using this regex (?<=<TN>.*?)\-(?=.*?</TN>)

Comment: it needs Java Regular Expression

Comment: it works! i use this expression (?!\<TN\>.*?)-(?=.*?\<\/TN\>)