# Remove angular brackets < and > from a string : Java regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking for a regular expression in Java where I can remove the beginning and end of the angular braces if both are present in the string.
e.g. 1

```
str = "abc <someting> def < 0"
output: "abc someting def < 0"
```

if there is either open or close then that brace should remain as it is.

e.g. 2

```
str = "abc <some <thing>> def < 0"
output : "abc some thing def < 0"
```

I followed other stackoverflow QA but nothing helped me.

Below are the one I tried

```
"\\<[^\\>]*?\\)"
"\\<|\\>"
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If you've got `some <angle <brackets>` as input, what should the output be: `some <angle brackets` or `some angle <brackets`?

Comment: Java regex doesn't support recursive patterns, better you use a parser.

Comment: @NickReed, OP seems to talk about well-balanced brackets, but not sure (upvoted comment though).

Comment: I personally like the `appendReplacement() and appendTail()` answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375420/java-equivalent-to-phps-preg-replace-callback but any call back way would work.
Each match, remove all `<` or `>` from group 0, then append (or replace) to the new string. Regex :
`"(?s)(?=<)(?:(?=.*?<(?!.*?\\1)(.*>(?!.*\\2).*))(?=.*?>(?!.*?\\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\\1)[^<]*(?=\\2$)"`

https://regex101.com/r/mbdquf/1 Note that each match is guaranteed to have balanced angle brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform a looping regexp replace until no changes are done. I assumed you were talking about bracket-free text surrounded by brackets. In that case, the regex is `<([^>]*)>`, which captures the inner text in the first group (named `$1`).

In the sample below, a **`while`** loop line checks if the `str` value is different than the result of `str.replaceAll()`,  which is assigned to `str` after<sup>1</sup> the check. If they are equals, the loop ends, i.e. nothing where replaced so there are no brackets to remove.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "abc <some <thing>> def < 0";
        while (!str.equals(str = str.replaceAll("<([^>]*)>", "$1")));
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
~$ javac Test.java
~$ java Test
abc some thing def < 0
```

---

<sup>1</sup> target reference of `str.equals()` is made [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59571839/4375327) the argument evaluation, so before the assignement.

Comment: [Comparing strings with `==` or `!=` is not safe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @VGR, you should remove your comment, since the answer was edited meanwhile.