# Evaluation order between a method call and arguments in Java

Tags: java, undefined-behavior, assignment-operator, evaluation, method-call

[Dealing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569692/4375327) with another SO question, I was wondering if the code below has an undefined behavior:

```
if (str.equals(str = getAnotherString())) {
  // [...]
}
```

I tend to think the `str` reference from which the `equals()` call is made is evaluated **before** the further `str` assignment passed as argument. Is there a source about it?

Comment: Definitely won't be undefined behaviour. Java has very few of those.

Comment: The code you posted is defined behavior. The answer is in the JLS, possibly under [15.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7).

Comment: Your though is correct. For if ```str = ...``` was evaluated first, the whole expression would always be true.

Comment: Evaluation order isn't the same thing as operator precedence.

Comment: Be aware of NPE in such case

Comment: @emotionlessbananas, The real method is `String.replaceAll()`, which should not return a null reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly specified in the [JLS Section 15.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4):

> At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target reference may be computed. Second, the argument expressions are evaluated. [...]

What's a "target reference" you ask? This is specified in the next subsection:

> **15.12.4.1. Compute Target Reference (If Necessary)**
>
> ...
>
> - If form is ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier, then:
>
>   - If the invocation mode is static, then there is no target reference. The ExpressionName is evaluated, but the result is then discarded.
>   - Otherwise, the target reference is the value denoted by ExpressionName.

So the "target reference" is the `str` bit in `str.equals` - the expression on which you are calling the method.

As the first quote says, the target reference is evaluated first, *then* the arguments. Therefore, `str.equals(str = getAnotherString())` only evaluates to true if `getAnotherString` returns a string that has the same characters as `str` before the assignment expression.

So yeah, the thing that you tend to think is correct. But this is not "[undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)".